# Prevent Conditional Formatting from Duplicating Rules

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet that has 5 rules that change the color of a row based on formulas. When users paste data into the worksheet, the conditional formatting for these rules duplicates. How can I prevent that?

Also, How would I set up VBA to automatically check the sheet after changes and correct formatting that is incorrect?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can force Paste Values via VBA if your workbook allows macros.